# Not able to reallocate memory in hard drive through disk management. hard disk partition not booting

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I had linux and windows 7 dual boot onn my system. I decided thought to remove Ubuntu due to grub problem. I overwrote the loader to get back my windows 7 to use since i was not able to boot in grub. After this I am not able to see the linux ubuntu partition on hard drive previously allocated.

The  hard drive partition is not booting.

I tried allocating

by going to disk management but getting an error while deleting the volume-"An unexpected error has occurred. Check the system event log for more information on the error."

Comment: What program are you using to look for the Ubuntu partition? So are you trying to get Ubuntu back, or to remove it entirely from the drive?

Answer (score 1):

Dual boot is done through chainloading. Grub, in your case, fires up, then passes the booting process to windows.

Since you removed grub, windows cannot boot.

At this point you will need a windows recovery disk/usb.

Choose "Repair Your Computer," go to "Troubleshoot," and then enter a Command Prompt. Type the following command:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern. My windows is booting. But the hard disk partition in which linux was previously installed is not visible in my computer.

Comment: The MBR is a tiny portion of your hardisk where bootloaders are (partly) installed. It does not have to do with partitions.

Comment: Rest of the partitions are visible. only the partition in which ubuntu was previously installed is not visible. i tried doing what you said but still the drive is not visible.